# How to get id's input in <td> by clicking on the another <td> field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm newbie with JavaScript and JQuery. I have two rows like this below

```
          <tr> 
             <td><label for="first_name">First Name</label>\</td> 

             <td id = "chessboard"><select name="first-name" id="first-name"><option value=""></option></select</td> 
         </tr> 

      <tr> 
        <td><label>Phone Number</label>\</td> 
        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="phone-number" id="phone-number"></td> 
      </tr>
```

What I want to do is when I click on the field of First Name, I will get the id's input from Phone Number row which should be "phone-number"

I have tried this below but it doesn't work

```
  $("#chessboard").on("click", function(cell){
     var y = document.getElementById('phone-number');
     console.log(y);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Make sure you set up your element event handlers after the document is 'ready'.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
   $("#chessboard").on("click", function(){
     var y = $("#phone-number").val();
     console.log(y);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake here is that you want to get the select element in the tr tag by its parent ID (tr). In fact, this is wrong! Because if the select element is clicked, the action to click the parent element (tr) will not be called. Therefore, you must refer directly to the select element itself:

```
$("#first-name").on("click", function(cell){
 var y = document.getElementById('phone-number');
 console.log(y);
```

Also to get the value of the element with ID number Phone:

```
var y = $( "#phone-number" ).val();
```